# Getting value of joined table Yii 2

Tags: php, mysql, join, yii2

Hello I am trying to access a value from a joined table schead.section to store in subjectcontainer.section, mainly I am using the scstock data but the section part is located in schead.section so what I did was to join the schead and schstock together so that I can have access to the section column. Here is what I did.

```
     $subject = ActiveCurriculum::find()
          ->select('scstock.*')
          ->leftJoin('schead', 'schead.TrNo = scstock.TrNo')
          ->where([ 'schead.TrNo' => $TrNo])
          ->one();

    $activesubject = new ActiveSubject();
    $activesubject->clientid = $clientid;
    $activesubject->TrNo = $subject->TrNo;
    $activesubject->subjectcode = $subject->subjectcode;
    $activesubject->schedday = $subject->schedday;
    $activesubject->schedtime = $subject->schedtime;
    $activesubject->section = $subject->section;
    $activesubject->room = $subject->room;
    $activesubject->units = $subject->units;
    $activesubject->save();
//reduces the slot of ccsubject by 1
     $subject->slots = $subject->slots - 1;
     //never forget the saving part
     $subject->save();
```

First `$subject` will access sctock table to join will schead via TrNo. then `$activesubject` will access subjectcontainer table to store the values in. Now my problem is I am getting this error.

[image]

Can someone help me in trying to solve this?

Comment: Try like this `->leftJoin('schead as sch', 'sch.TrNo = scstock.TrNo')->where([ 'sch.TrNo' => $TrNo])`

Comment: I have tried it is still getting the section as unknown property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to define relation to the `Schead` object in your model. Example of such relation:

```
/**
 * @property $schead Schead
 */
class YourModel extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * @return Schead
     */
    public function getSchead()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Schead::className(), ['field1' => 'field2']);
    }
}
```

Also, `$subject->schead.section` is a wrong way of accessing related model attributes. Use `$subject->schead->section` instead. If having schead is optional, don't forget to check existence of related object first, for example:

```
$subject->schead ? $subject->schead->section : null
```

Also check code for typos (probably `sched` / `schead`?). You can read more about working with relations in [official docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#relational-data).

Comment: How do I use this? In my case I have three files these are ActiveSubject.php (the place where I am joining the tables), Activecurriculum.php (this has the `tableName(){scstock}` ) and Schead.php where schead `tableName` is located.

Comment: @Quinlanlent Define it in model that has `schead` as relation.

Comment: Right I remembered to use `$subject->schead->section`

Comment: I have another question....what if I am using an array index like $subject['index'] how do I access an schead value?

Comment: @Quinlanlent Using a loop, for example `foreach ($subjects as $subject) { $schead = $subject->schead; }`.

Comment: Can I do this even I have already done a foreach loop? essentially doing a nested foreach? `<?php foreach($firstyearfirstterm as $subjects):?>`

Comment: @Quinlanlent I think it's a topic for different question.